# Soundcloud widget & for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, widget, soundcloud

i created music blog using soundcloud widgets. I trigger a button "Play all", so when you hit it, it plays all widgets.

```
$(function(){
    var playAll = $('.playAll');

    var widget0 = SC.Widget(playAll.find('iframe')[0]);
    var widget1 = SC.Widget(playAll.find('iframe')[1]);
    var widget2 = SC.Widget(playAll.find('iframe')[2]);

    widget0.bind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH,function() {
       widget1.play();
       widget0.unbind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH);
    });

    widget1.bind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH,function() {
        widget2.play();
        widget1.unbind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH);
    });


    $("#playSound").click(function() {
        widget0.toggle();
    });
});
```

It works, but what i'm trying to do is "for" loop, but because lack of js / jquery skills, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I love the enthusiasm to refactor code and the desire to use a higher level pattern, looping, instead of hard coding like you have. That being said the "middle space" problem is one of the harder problems to solve when iterating over a list.

You have to decide on a couple of things:

- You have a task your going to perform n-1 times so you have to decide if your going to skip the first element or the last.
- What task your going to perform in each iteration.
- What you'll do after the loop finishes.
- If you'll use a functional solution or a classic "for" loop.

Lets start with the task. We'll take the task from your example and put it in a function.

```
function connectFrames(now, next) {
  now.bind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH, function() {
    next.play();
    now.unbind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH);
  });
}
```

With this function we can use the index from our loop to pass in the current and next elements. The only exception will be when we are on the last element when there will be no "next", so that is the one we will skip. We will use the jQuery each for a modern / functional solution.

```
//One query to select all iframes inside .playAll
var playAll = $('.playAll iframe');

//The jQuery "loop" http://api.jquery.com/each/
playAll.each(function(index) {
  var now = playAll[index],
      next = playAll[index + 1];

  //If their is no next... skip.
  if(!next) return;

  //Use the frames we have in our function
  connectFrames(now, next);
});
```

The last thing we have to do is write in our final step which would be to start playing the content and we are done. Here is the complete code:

```
function connectFrames(now, next) {
  now.bind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH, function() {
    next.play();
    now.unbind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH);
  });
}

//One query to select all iframes inside .playAll
var playAll = $('.playAll iframe');

//The jQuery "loop" http://api.jquery.com/each/
playAll.each(function(index) {
  var now = playAll[index],
      next = playAll[index + 1];

  //If their is no next... skip.
  if(!next) return;

  //Use the frames we have in our function
  connectFrames(now, next);
});

//initiator from example
$("#playSound").click(function() {
    playAll[0].toggle();
});
```

Comment: Wow QueueHammer, thank you very much, it's like a gift on Happy New Year

Comment: I have a strange thing, playAll[0].toggle(); not firing first track.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the HTML looks somewhat like this :

```
<div class="playAll">
    <div>
        <iframe></iframe>
        <iframe></iframe>
        <iframe></iframe>
    </div>    
</div>
```

You get get the list of all iframes inside the div with class "playAll" (no matter the depth), and iterate:

```
var iframes = $(".playAll iframe");
for (i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {   
        // do something with iframes[i]
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/

Comment: Thank you zxzak for your answer, i created for loop, but the problem is now, when it iterates, it skips second track and goes all the way to third. So probably i need to add if statement.

Comment: The order of the elements in the array should be the same as in the DOM tree. Whether or not you need if statements, depends on your particular situation.